# Derived fields in Orbeon

Tags: xml, orbeon

Is there some way to derive field values from other fields in Orbeon CE with the help of perhaps some xml script?

I would like it to take some fields as in-parameters, do some calculations and then produce an out-parameter to put in a non-editable field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that this is for a form you're creating with Form Builder. If this is the case:

1. Name the "input" field, by clicking on the gear icon and typing a name. Say `first-name`.
2. Create a *text output* field, click on the *validation settings* icon next to the field, and in the dialog, in *Calculated Value*, type an XPath expression, say: `concat('Hello ', $first-name, '!')`. As you can see from this example, you can use the `$gaga` variable to refer to the field named `gaga`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any limitation on how long the expression can be?

Comment: There is no limitation on the length of the expression. The Form Builder UI (right now a simple text field) should be improve to better accomodate longer expressions, but you can certainly type the expression somewhere else, and paste it in that text field.